# What type of QR Code is generated by the Bing QR Code Generator

Tags: bing, qr-code

http://www.bing.com/widget/t/qrcode

Type in a number like 12345 - you will get a QR Code shown on the right.

Now go to a site like https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/

Type in 12345 in Free Text - the QR Code is different - it's very less dense as compared to the one generated by the Bing widget. I tried all the different options in https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/ - but none of them give the same QR Code as the Bing widget. And Bing's output scans fine with any QR Code scanner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to the level of error correction in the barcode. To be precise, the Bing generator can handle up to ~30% of the modules being damaged, where the QR Code Generator link can only handle up to ~7%.

You can tell the error correction level by looking at the two cells closest the bottom left corner, as per the image below:

[image]

<sub>From [here](http://blog.qrstuff.com/2011/12/14/qr-code-error-correction)</sub>

The more error correction, the more modules required to show the data. Which is fine unless you need to print it small, then the module size is also important.